# unique insert SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that has a relationship between an User_ID and a Role. User_ID can have many roles.

I have another table that has the orignal ID's (and some other info).

I need to write a bulk ingest kind of thing that will search through all ID's in Table1, and if there is no row in Table2 that has that ID with the Role "1", insert it. I have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [jsec_user_role_rel]
           ([version]
           ,[role_id]
           ,[user_id])
    SELECT 0, 1, id from jsec_user
    WHERE not exists(select * from jsec_user_role_rel where user_id = id);
```

Which seems to do the trick, but I get duplicate entries in the jsec_user_role_rel table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expand the `not exists` check to verify both `user_id` and `role_id`:

```
insert  [jsec_user_role_rel]
        ([version], [role_id], [user_id])
select  distinct 0
,       1
,       id 
from    jsec_user u
where   not exists
        (
        select  * 
        from    jsec_user_role_rel ur
        where   ur.user_id = u.id
                and ur.role_id = 1
        )
```

Otherwise you'll add a "1" role even for users that are already in the "1" role.

Answer (score 0):

I would try replacing your where statement with

WHERE ID NOT IN (select user_id from jsec_user_role_rel)

Comment: This is wrong, because user_id may be in the jsec_user_role_rel table, but with a different role than "1"

Comment: Then why not WHERE ID NOT IN (select user_id from jsec_user_role_rel WHERE role = 1) (or whatever necessary joins there is to get the role if it isn't in that table)